# Display D3 text labels only if variable has value

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3.js

Can I set the text element of a D3 shape to display only if a variable has a value?  In the code below, a rectangle renders but the width will change depending on the value of `selections` (an array of document ids).  If `selections` is empty, I still want the shape to render, but don't want any text label.  Right now, I am seeing $NaN.  Not sure where to include the if statement here.

```
Template.Box.onRendered (function () {
    const self = this;

    //List of variables to calculate dimensions
    var value = //Result of calculations
    var selections = Template.parentData(0).selections;
    var boxContainer = d3.select("#box" + boxId)
        .append("svg")
        .attr("id", "svg-box");

    var box = boxContainer.append("rect")
        .attr("x", start + "%")
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("width", range + "%")
        .attr("id", "box" + boxId);

    var boxValue = boxContainer.append("text")
        .attr("x", boxSpace + "%")
        .attr("y", "20px")
        .text(value)
        .attr("id", "low" + boxId);

    self.autorun(function() {
        //repeat code from above
    });
});
```

Comment: is value always a number?

Comment: Yes, but on initial render, the inputs needed to calculate that number do not yet exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your text attribute.

```
node.append("text")
    .style("display", function (d) { return (d.data.i) ? null : "none" })
```

If there is no d.data.i then it display is set to none.  Null means it will be displayed.